# How to split a multiple line INSERT INTO sql statement?

Tags: java, sql, regex

I want to anonymize values in a database given as a .sql file. To do that we parse the file in Java and foreach line we identify if it's an insert into. In that case we want to replace one of each values for a random string. Let's say 'Test1' for 'a38Xw', 'Test2' for 'e89cz' and 'Test3' for '389xb' in the following example:

```
INSERT INTO `user` VALUES (1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Test1',NULL,'\0'),
                          (7,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Test2',NULL,'abc'),
                          (8,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Test3',NULL,'abc');
```

The problem comes when the insert into has lots of values in the same line. We need to split the line for each register. We thought it could be a good idea to do it with a regular expression but we couldn't get with anything working as we are just new into this world.

Is this a valid approach? How we can be sure that we split the line in a correct way? How this regular expression will look like?

Comment: Your string replacement and line splitting seem like two unrelated problems. I do not understand why are you mixing them together while your question seems only about line splitting.

Comment: It was just to put you on context.

Comment: Regex isn't a great tool for this. It's still possible to do, but you'll encounter troubles such as handling textual values that contain closing brackets. Searching for a full-fledged SQL query parser could help you avoid all these troubles.

Comment: I think it depends much on the assumptions yo can make about the format/structure of the SQL statements that you need to parse. There may be a number of pitfalls (e.g. literals like 'INSERT INTO' coming as insert values, unexpected line breaks, and much more). If you need to be able to cope with anything, you might end up writing your own SQL lexer/parser - much beyond what a simple regex approach can do.

Comment: The same thing we also thought but we couldn't find a good one.
Do you have some good ones?

Comment: One more thought: Depending on the capabilities of your SQL RDBMS product, you may be able to solve the problem on the server side (e.g. using triggers).

Comment: it's not possible to do it on the server side

Comment: Do you have a good full-fledged SQL query parser? @Aaron

Comment: I have no experience on any but a websearch for "sql parser" returns a few promising results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would learn a dedicated SQL parsing library for this kind of job. Regular expressions are a useful tool but not powerful enough to capture all the little details of programming languages. You might manage to build a regex that will work 95% of the time but sooner or later it will break on some unexpected, but perfectly legal piece of SQL syntax.

You might want to give [JSqlParser](https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser) a try. It took me 10 minutes of browsing their repo to set up this example :

```
// testString is your example statement
Insert stmt = (Insert) CCJSqlParserUtil.parse(testString);
stmt.accept(new StatementVisitorAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void visit(Insert insert) {
        ItemsList list = insert.getItemsList();
        list.accept(new ItemsListVisitorAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void visit(ExpressionList expressionList) {
                Expression expression = expressionList.getExpressions().get(9);
                if (expression instanceof StringValue) {
                    StringValue val = (StringValue) expression;
                    expressionList.getExpressions().set(9, 
                        new StringValue(val.getValue().toUpperCase()));
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
System.out.println(stmt.toString());
```

With the given output :

```
INSERT INTO `user` VALUES (1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Test1', NULL, '\0'), 
  (7, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Test2', NULL, 'ABC'), 
  (8, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Test3', NULL, 'ABC')
```

This simply converts the last column values to uppercase, but you'll figure out the rest.

Comment: Thx for using JSqlParser :).